# Displaying a path from the database as a link, in my table

Tags: php, database, hyperlink, html-table, href

I'm trying to display a link in the report table I created by using the path that is stored in my database but I am having trouble figuring out how to correctly display it as a link to the image. So instead of the table showing different image I'll simply have a generic link that says "IMAGE LINK" or something and will take them to the image src via a href rather than displaying the images.

Here is how the data loops in the html table:

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$date=mysql_result($result,$i,"datetime");
$firstname=mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
$lastname=mysql_result($result,$i,"last");
$message=mysql_result($result,$i,"message");
$image=mysql_result($result,$i,"imagepath");

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $date . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $firstname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $lastname . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $message . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $image . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

$i++;
}
```

And here is the upload location and image path storage variable

```
//Where the file will be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

// Add the original filename to target path
$path= $target_path . basename($image);
```

The report page that shows the data is at the root with the uploads folder as well.
I've tried adding the image variable (in the loop) to a generic src link , but it displays nothing or breaks the table and generates syntax errors. This has me stumped.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: wasteful code. why not `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $row['datetime']; echo $row['first']`, etc...? much more efficient than your mysql_result business.

Comment: @Alex what is the syntax error that you're getting?

Comment: I forgot the error at this point, as I figured it out on my own shortly afterwards. Thanks for the support. I'll also be updating my mysql statements to mysqli. I should probably update my templates for simple connections as well. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<a href="<?php echo $target_path; ?><?php echo $image ?>">Image</a>`, If i'm right it will work.